# How do you explain that purely functional web servers like Ring and Yesod are not MVCs?

Tags: haskell, model-view-controller, clojure, functional-programming, yesod

Traditionally people think of web applications as an MVC - which assumes an Object Oriented context.

Functional programming critiques this - and offers a model using higher order functions and immutable data structures.

My question is: **How do you explain that purely functional web servers like Ring and Yesod are not MVCs?**

Comment: what makes you assume that MVC assumes OO? I'm not saying it does or not, but your statement makes me curious.

Comment: fwiw, there's a close mapping between objects and functions.  Both objects and functions can contain code and do things.  Purely functional programming doesn't allow imperative modification, as most OO does, but one of the first functional languages, Scheme, was developed by Steele and Sussman to [explore OO ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Scheme_programming_language) during the early days of OOP.   e.g. in Scheme you can define a function that's a closure over data and returns functions that allow imperatively modifying or examining that data.  Voila--function is object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

l will try to answer this with respect to Yesod.

> How do you explain that purely functional **web servers** like Ring and Yesod are not MVCs?

Yesod is not a web server. Yesod is a web framework. [warp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp) is the recommended web server for using alongside Yesod.

> How do you explain that purely functional web servers like Ring and Yesod are **not MVCs**?

That's not necessarily true. You can use the [templates](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates) as view, [persistent](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) as model and [routing and handing](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers) as Controller. In fact, the [scaffolding site](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/scaffolding-and-the-site-template) loosely follows the MVC approach.

> Functional programming critiques this - and offers a model using higher order functions and immutable data structures.

This has nothing to do with this MVC. MVC is just a design pattern. Higher order functions and immutable data structures doesn't stop you from following some architecture or a design pattern.

Answer (score 7):

You can assume OO context for MVC, and that's where it was born, but you certainly don't have to. MVC just says that Model, View and Controller should be separate things interacting in certain ways; in OO languages it's convenient to represent them as classes, but this isn't necessary. See e.g. [MVC and Purity](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/07/mvc-and-purity/):

> Having been exposed to purely functional programming, I now believe that the controller and model/view separation is precisely the separation between side-effectful code (IO) and pure code.

Answer (score 3):

Higher order functions and immutable data structures are what functional programming is about, just like classes/objects is what OOP is about, so it seems natural that a functional web server framework would primarily use the functional tools (functions, data structures) wherever possible.

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers begins with "If we look at Yesod as a Model-View-Controller framework," ... so I don't seem to quite understand your question. What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Ring is low-level enough that it doesn't make sense to talk about it as being MVC or not: it is just your adapter to the HTTP protocol. You can read the request headers/body, write response headers/body, and so on, but there's nothing in ring itself about updating domain objects; that's up to whatever you layer on top of ring.